# filepath for a image in server is not working

Tags: php, filepath

I am creating a PHP file, in which I am compressing images (using php func) that are present in a folder in a server and putting the compressed files into another folder.  Now the problem is I need to specify the path for both of the folders, for source folder, I simply gave:

```
HTTP://ipadrs/images/properties/thumbs_400/image_name (given "http "as HTTP purposely)
```

I checked if the image existed in the folder using `fopen` function, and its working perfectly.  I also gave the same path with '/compress_50/' appended to it after thumbs_400, but images are not getting compressed in resp folder; the same {H{ file is working perfectly in localhost.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening and what is the solution?

**EDIT:**  (Code posted in comments)

```
$img = HOME."images/properties/thumbs_400/".$sqlrow['plan_image_name']." "; 
$handle = fopen($img, "r"); 

if ($handle) { 
    $dest = HOME."images/properties/thumbs_400/compress_50/".$sqlrow['plan_image_name']." ";
```

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `HTTP://` rather than `HTTP//`?

Comment: this site didnt allow me to put http://while posting ques ,so i deliberately wrote it lyk that. thats all ,in my file i have given it as http:// only

Comment: That is not a valid URL with or without the `:` unless `ipadrs` is actually the ipaddress.  Add some code so that we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Buggabill i have given it as http:// only in ma code ,for code can u check the comments i have posted below ,sorry it was hard to add there .

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a Typing error, replace:

```
HTTP//ipadrs/images/properties/thumbs_400/image_name
```

with:

```
http://ipadrs/images/properties/thumbs_400/image_name
```

Comment: this site didnt allow me to put http://while posting ques ,so i deliberately wrote it lyk that. thats all ,in my file i have given it as http:// only

Comment: Oh, okay. So can you please append us some of your code? It is quite hard to guess the problem without any code!

Comment: $img  = HOME."images/properties/thumbs_400/".$sqlrow['plan_image_name']." ";
 
 $handle = fopen($img, "r");

 if ($handle)
 {
$dest =HOME."images/properties/thumbs_400/compress_50/".$sqlrow['plan_image_name']." ";

Comment: there was restriction in commenting ,so i have added only relevant code here and HOME is http://ipaddress ,and that $sqlrow is image name

Comment: Can you tell us what is the echoed code? also, is the format of the image included in the query? fopen requires the format too! (ex: you can't provide a link such HOME./location/filename! It needs to be like: home./location/filename.format! e.g.: if you have a .png image, try to add ".png" after $sqlrow['plan_image_name'] !